# Error involving ADO recordset and excel worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am attempting to execute the following code:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Step#2-PreSource$F3:F15]", cnn, _
            adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

I receive this error:

[image: Run-time error]

Notice in the error notification it converts the # sign to a period. There is in fact no existing object with such a name. Obviously this is not intended. Is there any way to work around an issue of this sort?

Comment: What connection string are you using?

Comment: Try this `['Step#2-PreSource'!$F3:F15]`. The single quotes may help solve the issue. And I am pretty sure you will need the `!` between the sheet name and range reference.